# Bypassing/Resetting Locked Win 10 Password

Tags: windows-10, passwords, password-recovery, reset, bypass

The church I go to gave me a computer and said I can have it an play with it. I seems to be the secretary's old Desktop. It is a Dell (maybe Windows 10) Desktop computer. They don't remember the password and all possible passwords they came up with were wrong. Being that I don't have any password for any account on the PC, I am having a very hard time resetting/bypassing the password. Is there any way I can bypass or reset the password? Any suggestion is helpful; best answer is the one that allows me to somehow get in.

Do note that as far as I know, any method that involves changing the boot order settings (if that is even the technical term for it) to get the PC to run a USB or CD won't work because that requires a password - a password I don't have and would like to get. Unless I misunderstood the directions. Even completely wiping it gives me troubles; I can't select any options when the "wiping wizard" (hardly not the technical term for it) runs. Thus I am coming here for you guys' wisdom and expertise on computers. Hopefully someone can help despite all of my attempts and limitations.

### More Info

The account is a local account and I have nothing to reset the password or retrieve it. I have at my dispense a USB I can use for any solutions. To specify, **I cannot log into the only account on the computer**. Just wanted to specify.

**UPDATE:** By removing the PSWD jumper, restarting the PC, shutting it down and putting the jumper back in, I have removed the admin password. Now what can I do from here?

### Why this is not a duplicate

As I have stated before, I am trying to log into a locked computer without using the password. I am not trying to gain admin rights of anything. Any answer in the question that needs to be longed into the PC to work won't work for me.

Comment: Also, I have and am looking around at other answers and so far, nothing is helping me

Comment: That does not help. The main difference is that I can't get in at all, while they at least can log in and change stuff

Comment: If the PC has a bios password you will have to reset that before you will be able to reinstall Windows

Comment: Funny, I was actually working on trying to do that

Comment: My suggestion pull the hdd and put a blank hdd in and reinstall Windows.  The boot order should allow you to install Windows if there isn't anything on the hdd

Comment: Reset the BIOS/UEFI password by changing the jumper/removing CMOS battery/whatever so you can enable DVD/USB booting. From there you should be able to enable the built-in administrator account from the command line with a Windows PE / Windows setup workaround (hopefully nobody set a password on that), and reset the password from within that account. see:http://www.isumsoft.com/it/enable-hidden-administrator-account-in-windows-10-without-login/

Comment: You may want a solution that doesn't require being logged in as admin, but the short answer is that every solution short of wiping the computer and resetting it entirely will require admin access to the computer. You could try to see if the computer has a recovery/repair/reset system provided by Dell. This would allow you to go back to a new, clean, fresh OS and would allow you to set up your own account(s).

Answer (score 1):

Try free Lazesoft Password Reset software to at least reset Admin password. Then you can create new user accounts. Normally you can get into the Bios to change boot order. Remove Bios battery if necessary!

Answer (score 1):

You can always use ophcrack (a simple google search will suffice) to retrieve the passwords using rainbow tables. All you have to do is load it on a usb stick, boot from in and let it work it's magic.

Trust me, this is no adware crap, i've used it before. It gets the job done.

Comment: I had tried it before you answered, I could not figure it out